# How to deploy a Django app onto a server that cannot use pip

Tags: python, django, deployment

I have a Django app that I need to deploy in a local intranet, which doesn't have internet access.  I will be bringing over my codebase with a USB key.

Typically, when deploying a Django app, the first thing you do is run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to gather all of your dependencies before launch.  How can you package up a Django application so that it is entirely self-contained, without requiring pip?

Comment: Does the machine have `virtualenv` installed?

Comment: @rnevius Nope.  It's an empty Windows box that is locked down.  I've installed Python 2.7 with the offline installer.

Comment: Is creating a docker or vagrant box an option? You could essentially pop either onto the machine and run them...I'm interested in hearing what others have to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install pip without internet access by copying this file first: [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

You'll then need to download the packages [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) from PyPI and place them in a local directory called `dependencies`. This directory will contain all required `.tar.gz` and/or `.whl` files.

You can then install `pip` by doing:

```
python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=dependencies
```

After that you can install all other dependencies (also in the `dependencies` directory) by doing:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=dependencies -r requirements
```

So you can download these separately and copy them along on the USB stick.

Comment: Copying over get-pip.py, I can't install pip without internet access.  Running ``python get-pip.py``, it tries to access https://pypi.python.org/simple/.

Comment: @Jim: can you copy the `pip` and `setuptools` packages from PyPI, add them to the `dependencies` directory and try: `python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=dependencies`?

Comment: Nice, that absolutely works.  I should have investigated get-pip.py in more detail.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Jim: good, I have updated my answer as this isn't something I do regularly. The answer should now contain all the steps needed to do this.